# Hibernate, listen or override to opneSession from a sessionFactory.openSession()

Tags: hibernate, transactions

The thing is that if you use

```
properties.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
```

Then Hibernate will put only `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` calls on `threadlocal` and not `sessionFactory.openSession()` calls.

`getCurrentSession` gets delegated to the `CurrentSessionContext` but `openSession` do not and they do not register either.

This is problematic if someone is attempting to register those as well. We want to use a `ThreadLocal` `List` where `getCurrentSession` will use the last on stack.

The current implementation seems to think that there is no need to manage also openSession calls, since they could not forsee some other potential use ( more correct use ).

So, am i left with overriding the entity `SessionFactoryImpl` class to hook in, or is there some **event that is triggered and I can hook into when a Session opens**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code, there's no way to plug into the behaviour of `openSession`. You could wrap your session factory in a `SessionFactoryDelegatingImpl` to reduce boilerplate.

Hooking into `getCurrentSession` is much easier, you will simply need to implement a custom `org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext`.

Comment: Yes, already done so. Both. So horrible. I am sure money crazed JBoss / RedHat have their reasons why everything is kept private and difficult to override. Even when we override the SessionFactory, we will only be able to override openSession() directly, but we can see in the SessionFactory implementation they call openSession() through other mechanisms, and not always through that method, which are kept private. We could however listen to the transaction begin on a session, using options.applyInterceptor(...)  but that is not the same thing and opted not to use that.

Comment: Also the default ThreadLocalCurrentSessionContext only supports one Session per thread, and will terminate any previous attached one, including freakingly rolling it back, silently, even catching any rollback exception and silently logging it. So ugly. Implemented a LinkedList based one instead.

Comment: I think perhaps one also needs to override withOptions method as well and provide a delagating SessionBuilderImpl. And it seems withStatelessOptions().

Comment: By the way, the Session seems to trigger some events in SessionImpl, pulse() and statisticts, actionQueue ? I could not figure out how to set up those things or if that is even a good idea. I am good now.